# Why do I get "script error" while using jQuery on IE 8?

Tags: jquery, yii, jquery-2.0

```
'clientScript' => array(
        'packages' => array(
            'jquery' => array(
                'baseUrl' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/',
                'js' => array('jquery.min.js'),
```

I'm using Yii Framework and the above code is in my **config/main.php**

The jQuery loads properly on all major browsers, but not on IE <= 8.

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this in footer layout to solve this problem, i have the same and i solve like this:

```
    <!--[if !IE]>-->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<?php

    // move all the scripts to footer and disable the default yii jquery
    Yii::app()->clientScript->coreScriptPosition=CClientScript::POS_END;
    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array(
        'jquery.js'=>false,
        'jquery.min.js'=>false,
    );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours, I found out that jQuery 2 doesn't support Internet Explorer 8 or lower anymore. So I did the change for the latest version of jQuery before version 2.

```
    'clientScript' => array(
            'packages' => array(
                'jquery' => array(
                    'baseUrl' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/',
                    'js' => array('jquery.min.js'),
```

Comment: As it states in [the docs](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-2-x) - **jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.**

Comment: @Vucko You're right. But I did think: "jQuery is cross-browser, so it supports IE8." Certain mistake...